# It's a small world after all?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

In the attached picture, the new icon looks small. In order for the ring to show up in the icon, the sphere gets shorter. While the ring is part of the large banner, I think the icon would fit in better if the ring were dropped and the sphere were scaled up to take the space.

[image: Small World]

Comment: I think we can find a middle ground, where the ring gets a little darker and smaller and the world gets a little larger.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Yeah, it might just be that the ring blends in, making it _look_ smaller.

Answer (score 3):

We've enlarged the world icon a bit, and darkened the halo. The halo does make it seem small compared to some of the other community logos that can span the entire width, but it's now bigger than it was.

Comment: I noticed that the icon of a WB chatroom is still a small planet with a bright ring. Can you change it in order to match the newest icon ?

Answer (score 1):

Ironically TJL we discussed and landed on the exact opposite (adding the ring and making it more pronounced) when we discussed the site design after it was originally delivered.

Comment: I missed that conversation. :(

Comment: @T.J.L.  I think it was in here somewhere.  http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design?rq=1

Comment: @James Yep, [here's the suggestion](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2917/29) and [here's the comment pointing it out](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design?rq=1#comment8015_2916).